# Early 80's Sci-Fi book about an undercover alien on Earth sending footage back to his home planet

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

It is about an alien under cover on Earth. He looks human but is smarter and very fit. He races cars to make money. He has a camera implanted which sends back video with all he hears and sees. The camera fails to transmit when he is with a woman or discussing things to not give all the information back to his corrupt handler on his home planet. I think it was a series and this was the first.

Comment: Can you remember why the alien was on Earth? Why were they recording Earth? How was the handler corrupt? When you say it fails to transmit, is there some problem or is he disabling it? Was he ever found out to be an alien? By who? If you remember anything else to add in please [edit] those details into your question.

Comment: About 25 years ago, I checked out a book from a public library. Specifically, it was *The Invaders Plan,* book 1 of a 10-part series ("Mission Earth") by L. Ron Hubbard. I don't remember if the hero had a video camera implanted in his body, but he was working undercover on Earth on behalf of an alien empire. The series was supposed to be satirical, but I found it boring rather than amusing, so I have no intention of rereading it to check whether it matches the points you remember. I'm just offering this comment. (If someone else wants to describe it better in a detailed Answer, be my guest!)